# firebase cloud functions change name when deploying

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Few weeks ago, I created and deployed few cloud functions but now when i wanted to make some changes my functions are deployed with "-default" suffix and firebase didn't see the previous functions, I didn't change any names or export methods, anyone has an idea why it is happening?

This is how my function in firebase console look like:
[image]

This is my function export from index.ts

*index.js*

```
exports.newGame = newGame;
exports.newRound = newRound;
exports.syncTime = syncTime;
exports.checkAnswersStatus = checkAnswersStatus;
exports.checkVotesStatus = checkVotesStatus;
```

And this is how i create a new function:

*newGame.ts*

```
const newGame = functions.https.onCall( async (data:any,context:any)  => {

<function content>
});

export default newGame;
```

Comment: Hmm that's certainly odd. Can you share a little more about your project structure and how the functions are being imported in `index.js` (or `index.ts`)? Firebase Function names are derived from the name of the function as exported in `index.js`. I suspect that `export default` could be appending the `.default` somewhere, but I'm not sure how this could be happening on your codebase.

Comment: export default newGame; - this how I exporting function and this is how I importing it in index.js : const newGame = require('./newGame');

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue